# Getting the relative path to main executable C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to do what I thought was a relatively easy task to do, at runtime I would like to obtain the path of the executable to be able to use this directory to create a subdirectory for storing my settings xml file

```
public  ProgramSettings()  
{
    filePath =  Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\Settings\";
}
```

I build the debug build, this run fine - but I was expecting that if I move the executable to another location (or computer for that matter) it should pickup the new location. This code still returns the original path of the Visual Studio environment even on another machine. Can someone please explain what is going on???

Comment: It doesn't reproduce. Are you sure `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` always returns the path when the executable is built by Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```cs
public ProgramSettings()
{
    var baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProgramSettings)).Location);
    string fullPath = $"{baseDir}\\Settings\\";
}
```